# Rollback function is not working properly in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, rollback

I have written a code to enter the record, if first record is entered than only second can be entered, if second fails than first will rollback and no change should occurred

```
<?php
include '../function.php';
// Set autocommit to off
mysqli_autocommit($mysqli,FALSE);
// Insert some values 
$a=mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO test VALUES ('10','2')");
if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0)
{
    $b=mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO test VALUES ('7','2')");
    if($mysqli->affected_rows > 0){
        mysqli_commit($mysqli);   
        echo "commited";
    }
    else{
        mysqli_rollback($mysqli);
        echo "rollback";
    }    
}else{
        echo "nothing";
}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

But above code is making my first record rollback if second record is failed to save.

Comment: You need to commit the first one before adding the second one if you want them to be separate transactions; otherwise the whole transaction is rolled back (i.e. both records).

Answer (score 0):

suggest you to use begin_transaction and try catch function.  below is the example:

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "sakila");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
try {
    mysqli_begin_transaction($link, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

    mysqli_query($link, "Insert statement 1");
    mysqli_query($link, "Insert statement 2");
    mysqli_commit($link);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        mysqli_rollback();
    }
```

Comment: There is no error if query is not completed properly, so commit is running all the times